# Select Query in php not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
$dateBegin=date( 'Y-m-d');
$dateEnd=date( 'Y-m-d');

// $sql = "SELECT smsno FROM SMSTRAN where smsdate BETWEEN '$dateBegin' AND '$dateEnd' ";

// $sql = "SELECT smsno FROM SMSTRAN WHERE STR_TO_DATE(smsdate,'Y-m-d') between STR_TO_DATE('$dateBegin','Y-m-d') and STR_TO_DATE('$dateEnd','Y-m-d') ";

$sql = "SELECT smsno FROM SMSTRAN WHERE smsdate BETWEEN '".$dateBegin." 00:00:00' AND '".$dateEnd." 23:59:59' ORDER BY smsno ";
```

I am getting syntax error of select query, I tried different ways to retrieve records, earlier sql statments are commented, all not worked?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm wondering why you have whitespace before your first param on date() function?

Comment: Print `$sql ` on next line and Use the same statement in mysql admin. Tell us what do u get .

Comment: @Jackhardcastle , It still does not matter , code runs

Comment: I know @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com, hence why I started with "unrelated", I was just curious is all.

Comment: just show us `var_dump($sql)` to help you please

Comment: Sir My second query is wrong, but for first query commented I am getting as follows - SELECT smsno FROM SMSTRAN where smsdate BETWEEN '2015-04-14' AND '2015-04-14' 
and for third query I am getting this 
SELECT smsno FROM SMSTRAN WHERE smsdate BETWEEN '2015-04-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-14 23:59:59' ORDER BY smsno 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1  - For both common error message as shown in last

Answer (score 0):

Last query worked when I inserted one record in mysql table SMSTRAN. Earlier there was no data in mysql table hence it was not working